# Android NFC Tag Read. intent always null

Tags: java, android, android-intent, nfc

I am trying to read an NFC tag when the app is opened (opened automatically when I scan the tag), but I can't seem to read the payload.  In fact, I can't seem to pick the tag up at all.  I have used another app to read the tag's mime type and payload - everything seems fine.

Apologies if this is an obvious one - I have read the documentation and checked various other sources before posting, to no avail.

There are no errors I can see and code compiles fine.
Code below.  Logcat shows:

`08-30 20:15:50.248: E/Activity...(3703): Hello world.  Intent Type: null`:

```
package com.spotsofmagic.spotsofmagic;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.nfc.NdefMessage;
import android.nfc.NdefRecord;
import android.nfc.NfcAdapter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    private static final String TAG = "Activity...";
    private NfcAdapter mAdapter;
    private TextView mTextView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

        // grab our NFC Adapter
        mAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);

        // TextView that we'll use to output messages to screen
        mTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_view);

        displayMessage("Loading payload...");
        // see if app was started from a tag and show game console
        Intent intent = getIntent();


        Log.e(TAG, "Hello world.  Intent Type: "+ intent.getType());
```

Manifest file;

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="14" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc" android:required="true" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

     <activity
        android:name=".CardActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <!-- Handle a collectable card NDEF record -->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"/>
            <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.spotsofmagic.bluetoothon"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
     </activity>

</application>
```

Comment: Could you show the contents of the manifest file?

Comment: Sure. I've just edited the post and popped it at the bottom.

Comment: I can't get the type too but I can do `intent.getAction()` if that helps any. With this I know that the intent isn't null - well for me your case might be different.

Comment: The NFC intent filter is for CardActivity, not for MainActivity. So I would expect that the problem is in CardActivity.

Comment: Ah!  I think that's the issue :) Let me check, then if it is just pop it in and answer and I'll mark it correct

Comment: Kind of sorted it. That was obviously an issue, but CardActivity doesn't ever seem to be getting called.  I've placed a `Log` call right at the top of the file, but get nothing.  CardActivity.java here: http://pastie.org/private/wk6zos6shuhfkzqjh9v4a

Comment: I'll ask in another question actually, if you can pop what you said in an answer I'll mark it as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NFC intent filter is for CardActivity, not for MainActivity. So I would expect that the problem is in CardActivity.